# Groovy: Seems like a scope issue but cannot find where, can you?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote some functions to help me writing Jenkins pipelines.

The following functions, are responsible to returning a shell command output:

```
def gen_uuid(){
    randomUUID() as String
}

def sh_out(cmd){
    String uuid = gen_uuid()
    sh """( ${cmd} )> ${uuid}"""
    String out = readFile(uuid).trim()
    sh "set +x ; rm ${uuid}"
    return out
}
```

That shown, here's another function:

```
Map get_started_by(){
  withCredentials([ // Use Jenkins credentials ID of artifactory
      [$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '0b8d591a-f4ce-XXXX-XXXX-faecb504d3d0', usernameVariable: 'J_USER', passwordVariable: 'J_PASS'],
  ]){
    List startedBy = sh_out("""
        set +x; curl -u ${J_USER}:${J_PASS} '${env.BUILD_URL}api/json' 2>/dev/null | \
        python -mjson.tool | \
        awk -F'"' '/(userId|userName)/{print \$4}'
    """).split(/(\n)/)
    return [
        userId: startedBy[0],
        userName: startedBy[1]
    ]
  }
}
```

Which returns the userId and userName of the user who issue the job run.

Then, my problem is in this function:

```
def run_in_stage_func(String stage_name, Closure command, String sendTo){

  String started_by = get_started_by()
  String ulink = "<@${started_by['userId']}>"
  String jlink = "(<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"

  println "============================================================"
  stage (stage_name) {
      try {
          command()
          if (currentBuild.result == 'FAILURE') {
              error "Build failed, see log for further details."
          }
          println "============================================================"
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          def except = "${ex}"
          slackSend channel: channel, color: 'danger', teamDomain: null, token: null,
              message: " :${ulink} *Failed to build ${env.JOB_NAME}*! :x: ${jlink} (<!here|here>)"
          echo "Pipeline failed at stage: ${stage_name}"
          throw ex
      }
  }
}
```

When I run the job, I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: userId for class: java.lang.String
```

What could be the reason that the line ' String ulink = "<@${started_by['userId']}>" ' - is not working as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cast the result of `get_started_by()` to `String` explicitly. To fix it, change your code to

```
def started_by = get_started_by()
```

or

```
Map started_by = get_started_by()
```